# How can automate this section of grid.arrange function in R

Tags: r

I have a code chunk that looks like this:

```
p1 <- plotQC(sce_1, type = "highest-expression")
p2 <- plotQC(sce_2, type = "highest-expression")
p3 <- plotQC(sce_3, type = "highest-expression")
p4 <- plotQC(sce_4, type = "highest-expression")
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4,ncol=2)
```

This works very well and has no errors or warnings.

I want to put a loop around. What I have done is

```
 for (i in 1:length(paths))
    assign(paste0("p",i), plotQC(get(paste0("sce_",i)), type = "highest-expression"))
    grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4,ncol=2)
```

The second chunk also works very well.However, I would like to make grid.arrange work without manually telling it about p1,p2,p3,p4 but it should detect it the number of p objects.

How can I do this? I am working in R markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep with your loop, you could also try this:

```
p.list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(paths)){
  p <- plotQC(get(paste0("sce_",i)), type = "highest-expression")
  p.list[[i]] <- p
}
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = p.list)
```

Here, instead of assigning the plot, we save it in a list called p.list, then we build your grid from the list. I used `plot_grid` from `cowplot` because it accepts a list of plots as an argument, and I find it easier to work with the plot grid overall.

Answer (score 1):

While all this works, I think you'll agree that the following is better as it in no place requires you to repeat any of the lines or manually specify some numbers:

```
sce <- list(sce_1, sce_2, sce_3, sce_4)
p <- lapply(sce, plotQC, type = "highest-expression")
do.call(grid.arrange, c(p, ncol = 2))
```

In particular, working with lists is much better in such cases. For this purpose you probably should produce `sce_1`, ..., `sce_4` also differently, as list elements.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I will keep it in mind for next time.:)